# what does JYADXW mean as a HTTP verb?

Tags: http, log-files, apache-2.4, traffic, request

Some jerk attacked my server, and I was reading the logs, when I saw "JYADXW" where the HTTP verb  GET/POST/OPTIONS normally reside. What is this request? what does it mean?

```
malicious IP Here - - [26/Sep/2014:06:12:01 -0400] "JYADXW / HTTP/1.1" 403 520 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"
```

Comment: 520  CloudFlare's reverse proxies to signal an "unknown connection issue between CloudFlare and the origin web server" to a client in front of the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the full list of HTTP request methods in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4).

An attacker was probably assessing what your web server does with an invalid request.